# Serve html file with fs.readFileSync() fails

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this code (https://gist.github.com/2402116) :

```
server.get('/', function(request, response) {
 var k = fs.readFileSync('./index.html','utf8');
 response.send( k );
});
```

Tries to read this file:

https://gist.github.com/2402070

and the browser keeps loading and never end.

But if I remove all the js includes from the html file works fine.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What does your "app.js" file do?  It seems like you've narrowed it down to something in that code, no?

Comment: app.js has all the front-end logic. I'm thinking it has to do with the encoding at the time it tries to send the file data to the browser.

Comment: You can use the profiling tool in your browser's developer tools to see where it's getting caught up - script execution, network, rendering etc..

Comment: You need to actually write code to serve your static files..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your [current server implementation](https://gist.github.com/2402116) does not do anything but serve `index.html` to requests for the base url, i.e. `'/'`. You will need to write further code/routes to serve the requests for the js includes in your `index.html`, i.e. `'/app.js'` and the various js files in `'/js/'`.

Now, the routing implementation in the gist is quite crude and doesn't support many aspects of url matching. The original code is clearly just demonstrating a concept for a single page site with no resources. You will see it will quickly become burdensome to get your code working as you will effectively have to write a route for every resource request, e.g.

```
server.get('/app.js', function(request, response) {
  var k = fs.readFileSync('./app.js','utf8');
  response.send( k );
});

server.get('/js/jquery-1.7.2.js', function(request, response) {
  var k = fs.readFileSync('./js/jquery-1.7.2.js','utf8');
  response.send( k );
});

etc...
```

You are better off looking at a node.js url routing library already out there (e.g. [director](https://github.com/flatiron/director)) or a web framework such as [express](http://expressjs.com) which has inbuilt support for [routing](http://expressjs.com/guide.html#routing) (and static file serving).

Answer (score 2):

You need a `response.end()` once you are done sending data to your browser.

Actually, since you are sending all of your data at once, you can just replace `response.send(k)` with `response.end(k)`.  Although this method is not recommended.  I highly recommend reading your file asynchronously and sending it to the client chunk-by-chunk.

See also:  http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_response_end_data_encoding

Comment: If you look at the first gist `send` is a custom implementation which includes `end()`.

Answer (score 1):

try `.toString` on k and not send but `.end`

```
response.end( k.toString() );
```

maybe some wierd things happens and he tries to eval the code